# Stringstream don't copy new lines

Tags: c++, stringstream

Special characters disappear when I pass a string into a stringstream.
I tried this code which can directly be tested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 string txt("hehehaha\n\t hehe\n\n<New>\n\ttest:\t130\n\ttest_end:\n<New_end>\n");

 cout << txt << endl; // No problem with new lines and tabs

 stringstream stream;
 stream << txt;
 string s;
 while(stream >> s) {
  cout << s;  // Here special characters like '\n' and '\t' don't exist anymore.
 }
 cout << "\n\n";

 return 0;
}
```

What can I do to overcome this?

Edit: I tried this:

```
stream << txt.c_str();
```

and it worked. But I don't know why...

Comment: you are aware of that >> splits at arbitrary whitespace?

Comment: I was not. But when I use not a stringstream but a ifstream, then I do ifstream >> char, whitespaces are not ignored but passed to the char. Why would it be different now I am using stringstream?

Comment: @AlexandreToqué >> char is not the same as >> string

Comment: I got that, What Im saying is: stringstream >> char and ifstream >> char are not alike.

Answer (score 2):

basically, you are just printing it wrong, it should be:

```
cout << stream.str() << endl;
```

Some details. You are calling [operator<<(string)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/) which

> overloads operator<< to behave as described in ostream::operator<<
>   for c-strings

The referred to behaviour is explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/):

> (2) character sequence Inserts the C-string s into os. The terminating
>   null character is not inserted into os. The length of the c-string is
>   determined beforehand (as if calling strlen).

Strlen [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) says that the result is affected by nothing but

> the terminating null-character

Indeed, `strlen(tmp)` in your examples outputs 55.

The stream, hence, gets "assigned" everything which comes up to the 55th character in your input string.

```
cout << stream.str() << endl;
```

will show you that this is indeed what happens.

A parenthesis: you can modify the behaviour of the `stream << txt` line by means of setting/unsetting flags, as in

```
 stream.unsetf ( std::ios::skipws );
```

which you should try out.

Comment: If I unset the skipws flags then cout << stream.str() << endl works.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
while(stream >> s)
```

Is the problem, it gives you one token on each call, using white spaces for splitting and therefor ignoring them.

Comment: Yes I saw that, However replacing it with a char does not solve the problem.